# How to copy and paste a large number of tasks in the same project file?

Tags: ms-project

I have a schedule broken down by building number (bldg. 1-39); I have inputted the tasks for bldg. 1 (approx. 200) and need to copy and paste this to the other 39 buildings. I can't seem to do this without everything shifting (losing a bldg. etc.) Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common task in scheduling as projects often have similar blocks of tasks. With MS Project, the key is to collapse the tasks to a summary level before you copy/paste them.

**Steps for duplicating blocks of tasks:**

1. Create a summary task and name is something like "Building 1".
2. Move all the tasks for this building under the summary task.
3. Collapse the summary task so all you see is the one summary row.
4. Select that row and copy it (Ctrl+C).
5. Select the next blank row and paste (Ctrl+V).
6. Collapse the new summary task.
7. Repeat steps 5 & 6 until you have a summary task for each building.
8. Rename the new summary tasks as appropriate.

Comment: @NatashaMercey Glad this was helpful; don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: keep up with your great answers on ms-project, always a pleasure to read them. This discussion about ms-project related tags might be of interest to you, https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/833/27189 . Basically the tags are not being properly used accordingly to the rules. From a recent discussion we understand 1-2 edits are day are understandable, https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/853/27189 .

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I have no idea why you added this comment.

Comment: Would be great to understand your POV as a user writing mostly for ms-project tag. Have you missed any question through the conventional method of tag watching or didn't increase your ms-project tag score due to having the tags wrongly used in a question? (Maybe you didn't even think of this?)

Comment: Ah yes, I might miss questions due to (mis)tagging. I’ll review my filters.